# How to Call my custom PasswordResetSerializer? (Django - DRF)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, reset-password

I want to use my custom PasswordResetSerializer to send the email automatically after the user reaches the limits of login attempts

This custom serializer works fine in my frontend via API call, but I want to use it in my authentication backend (see authentication.py last line)

Here is my code:

**authentication.py**

```
class ExampleAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        username = request.data.get('email', None)  # get the username request header
        password = request.data.get('password', None)

    """
    After all validations and login attempts

    """
    if user.fails_authentication():
        #Use here my custom PasswordResetSerializer
```

Here is my custom serializer

**serializers.py**

```
class PasswordResetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password_reset_form_class = PasswordResetForm
    def validate_email(self, value):
        self.reset_form = self.password_reset_form_class(data=self.initial_data)
        if not self.reset_form.is_valid():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_('Error'))

        ###### FILTER YOUR USER MODEL ######
        if not User.objects.filter(email=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_('Invalid e-mail address'))
        return value

    def save(self):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        user = User.objects.get(email=request.data.get('email'))
        token = Token.objects.get(user=user.id)
        uid = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.id)).decode()
        template = 'example_message.html'
        context = {'usertoken': token, 'reactdomain': 'localhost:3000', 'userid': uid}
        opts = {
        'use_https': request.is_secure(),
        'from_email': getattr(settings, 'DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL'),

        ###### USE YOUR TEXT FILE ######
        'email_template_name': template,
        'extra_email_context': context,
        'html_email_template_name': template,
        'request': request,
        }
        self.reset_form.save(**opts)
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please elaborate it more and clearly mention what you want with examples.

Comment: you should track your fail attempts.

Comment: @shourav Im already in control of that, the only thing I want to do is call the custom serializer inside my authentication.py